# Worldpay Mocking in PHPUnit

Tags: phpunit, worldpay

I have a website allowing people to sign up to a subscription service with a credit card, which I'm handling through their "own form" solution - https://developer.worldpay.com/jsonapi/docs/own-form

It's working, but I need to write PHPUnit tests, and I don't know how to mock the form being submitted correctly, as it relies on javascript to turn a number of secure form elements into a $_POST[token] item.

Can anyone help with showing how to write tests for this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't test their service or anything related as part of your unit test. That would be an integration test.

You should encapsulate your code from the external api and use stubs and drivers to emulate whatever their form would communicate with your code.